# Traducir los permalinks usando el plugin "qTranslate-X"

Tags: plugin, wordpress

Quisiera saber si es posible traducir los permalinks usando el plugin [`qTranslate-X`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/) y en caso de que el plugin no lo permita quisiera saber cómo puedo hacerlo.

Por ejemplo:

- http://www.misitio.com/es/casa - Para contenido en español.
- http://www.misitio.com/en/house - Para contenido en inglés.

Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Comment: ¿Has probado con [QTranslate Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/)?, liga de referencia: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/sef-permalinks-with-qtranslate-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El componente QTranslate es bueno para traducción de sitios que usan WordPress, pero carece de muchas cosas y para compensar aquellos conflictos podemos recurrir al addon (para qtranslate) **QTranslate Slug**. Esta herramienta añade soporte para traducciones de los permalinks, corrigiendo deficiencias que tenemos con QTranslate.

#### Requisitos

- QTranslate instalado.

#### Cambiar el motor de permastructure

1. Administrador > Configuración > Slug options.
2. Establecer la base permastructs para entradas y taxonomías.
3. Guardar ajustes.

#### Ejemplo en caso de uso

Versión en español:

```
dominio.com/acerca-de-nosotros
```

Versión en inglés:

```
dominio.com/en/acerca-de-nosotros
```

---

#### Información adicional

- Fuentes de apoyo:

  - [Como traducir las URL/permalinks con qtranslate](http://reinspirit.com/como-traducir-las-urlpermalinks-con-qtranslate/)
  - [Qtranslate-slug](http://not-only-code.github.io/qtranslate-slug/)
- Plugin: [QTranslate Slug](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-slug/faq/)
- Respositorio oficial (Github): [not-only-code/qtranslate-slug](https://github.com/not-only-code/qtranslate-slug)